# Recently I earned a hat but it displays weird in my Profile

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2016

Recently I earned the hat `abominable`. But when I set it to my profile means wear a Hat. It is display weird behavior.

**see the Image :**

[image]

As I am saw this profile no one can know that I am wearing a hat.

**Suggestion :** to improve the hat and add face detection to it. To wear hat on a profile display beautiful.

Comment: Do yo Hate Hat, What?

Comment: Before applying hat click on show controls so you can resize and change the position of hat to your profile pic.

Comment: @Tushar No  I am just give the suggestion to wear it beautiful not as display in my profile.

Comment: Okay. You can reduce the hate by controls provided when applying the hate to avatar.

Comment: Okay thank for you suggestion and help.

Comment: Wear all the hate.

Comment: you can make it smaller !